# How to pass JS date to AWS Cognito DateTime using Amplify field

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify w/ Cognito for registering new users. I have two custom DateTime properties that I want to send my data to. When I try to pass JS date to it, I keep getting error that the datetime format is invalid:

```
const date = new Date();

Auth.signUp({
  ...
  attributes: {
    'custom:mydate': date.toISOString()
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Cognito custom fields with the DateTime type, you must pass timezone values UTC (2022-12-30 10:13:43 UTC)

```
const date = new Date();
    
    Auth.signUp({
      ...
      attributes: {
        'custom:mydate': `${moment.utc(date).format('yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')} UTC`
      }
    });
```